# I can not get data to aggregate It. PHP + mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

It works like I need:

```
    $out = $collection->aggregate(
        array(
            '$match' => array('type' => 'chair')
        ),
        array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'chairtype' => 1,
                    'mijczjeqeo'=>1
                )
        ),
        array( 
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$chairtype', 
                'MIDDLE_mijczjeqeo' => array('$avg' => '$mijczjeqeo'),
                'SUMMA__mijczjeqeo' => array('$sum' => '$mijczjeqeo')
            )
        )
);
my_dump($out);
```

But i need to get true data for aggregation from array in the same documents: versions[0][content][mijczjeqeo]

Please correct my script. It does not work:

```
$out = $collection->aggregate(
        array(
            '$match' => array('type' => 'chair')
        ),
        array(
                '$project' => array(
                    'chairtype' => 1,
                    'versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo'=>1
                )
        ),
        array( 
            '$group' => array(
                '_id' => '$chairtype', 
                'MIDDLEmijczjeqeo' => array('$avg' => '$versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo'),
                'SUMMAmijczjeqeo' => array('$sum' => '$versions[0]["content"]["mijczjeqeo"]')
            )
        )
);
```

no one method does not work:

'MIDDLEmijczjeqeo' => array('$avg' => '$versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo')

'SUMMAmijczjeqeo' => array('$sum' => '$versions[0]["content"]["mijczjeqeo"]')

I think the problem near .0.

I try to do it in mongo console...

```
db.documents.aggregate({$match:{'type':'chair'}},{$project:{'chairtype': 1, 'mijczjeqeo':1}},{$group:{'_id':'$chairtype','MID':{$avg:'$mijczjeqeo'}}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "T",
            "MID" : 6.615384615384615
        },
        {
            "_id" : "G",
            "MID" : 8.310344827586206
        },
        {
            "_id" : "E",
            "MID" : 6.9523809523809526
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}

db.documents.aggregate({$match:{'type':'chair'}},{$project:{'chairtype': 1, 'versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo':1}},{$group:{'_id':'$chairtype','MID':{$avg:'$versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo'}}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : "T",
            "MID" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "G",
            "MID" : 0
        },
        {
            "_id" : "E",
            "MID" : 0
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: `'$versions[0]["content"]["mijczjeqeo"]'` should be `'$versions.0.content.mijczjeqeo'`

Comment: like first one and it doesn't work (((

Comment: Did you get it working? Was about to investigate more

Comment: Yesterday you helped me with string to float conversion. I don't know why it does not work

Comment: You said thanks for the help, I thought you got the aggregation working

Comment: I said thanks because you try to help me for 2 days )))

Comment: Oh ok, well what is the result after adding my fix?

Comment: no result... and in mongo console the same... I edited post

Comment: Hmm its not no result but a zero result, hmmmm I might need to just play around with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you cannot project like that in the aggregation pipeline. If you want to act on array elements within an aggregation statement you first need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array and then either [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) the required element(s) or as in your case choose the [**`$first`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) item using an additional [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

Your question does not show the structure of a document so I'll just use a sample, as my "chairs" collection:

```js
{
    "_id": 1,
    "type": "chair",
    "chairtype": "A",
    "versions": [
        {
           "revision": 1,
           "content": {
               "name": "ABC",
               "value": 10
           }
        },
        {
           "revision": 2,
           "content": {
               "name": "BBB",
               "value": 15
           }
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id": 2,
    "type": "chair",
    "chairtype": "A",
    "versions": [
        {
           "revision": 1,
           "content": {
               "name": "CCC",
               "value": 20
           }
        },
        {
           "revision": 2,
           "content": {
               "name": "BAB",
               "value": 12
           }
        }
    ]
}
```

Minimal, but enough to get the point. Now the aggregate statement:

```js
db.chairs.aggregate([

    // Normal query matching, which is good
    { "$match": { "type": "chair" } },

    // Unwind the array to de-normalize
    { "$unwind": "$versions" },

    // Group by the document in order to get the "first" array element
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "chairtype": { "$first": "$chairtype" }, 
        "versions": { "$first": "$versions" } 
    }},

    // Then group by "chairtype" to get your average values
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$chairtype", 
        "MID": {"$avg": "$versions.content.value"} 
    }}

])
```

Of course if your actual document has nested arrays then you will be "unwinding" and "matching" the required elements. But that is the general process of "narrowing down" the array contents to the elements you need.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23063840/aggregate-mongo-data-php thank you